# angular 4 httpclient get body of post request on error

Tags: angular

I'm trying to find an example of how to get the body of a POST request (queryObj below) in case of an error, but I can't find one:

```
this.http.post<ApiResponse>(
        url,
        queryObj,
        { headers: new HttpHeaders(headers), observe: 'response' }
    ).subscribe(
       resp => { ... },
       err => { // get queryObj }
    )
```

Thanks.

Comment: why not just built the object you're passing in the request?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the `queryObj` Object, it is the one you are sending, in the `error` part of the subscribe you´re getting an exception from the post service, it should raise if your request is not successful, in that case just show queryObj and some error like this:

//define previously this.error and this.response, of course

```
this.http.post(url, queryObj, { headers: new HttpHeaders(headers) })
    .subscribe(
       resp => { 
          this.response = resp;
          // ... whatever action you wanna perform here
       },
       err => { 
          this.error = err;
          console.log("Request failed due to " + this.error);
          console.log("Body of the post request: ");
          console.log(queryObj);
       });
```